# Email articles from Google News

Tags: google-news

Regarding the below screenshot:

[image]

Earlier, I could email articles `natively` from Google News. I.e., on clicking the **envelope icon** on any article, an overlay appeared where you could add recipient email addresses, aided by auto-complete from Gmail Contacts. The email was delivered in the below format:

[image]

Now, the envelop icon in Google News is merely a `mailto:` hyperlink which opens a compose email window, in your default email program, with a subject line and **ONLY ONE** URL in the body, as shown in the below screenshot where Gmail is my default email program.

[image]

This sucks.

- Is anybody else having this issue?
- How to revert back the old behaviour?

Comment: I'm seeing it to. It makes sense, I suppose. The old way would have required a significant amount of processing on their end. This way, virtually none. And there's no way to go back, I'm afraid, unless they re-implement it.

Comment: Another thought occurs to me: It may have been used to send too much unsolicited email.